# Wordpress condition if page is help in array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, variables, var

Its been a long time since I have done php, Im trying to set a var with a array inside then call that var within a array.. now im typing it seems wrong..

I get "undefined var error" anyone know what i doing wrong here ?

```
$myvar = array(
    'templates/page-one.php',
    'templates/page-two.php');

function se_remove_styles() {
    if ( is_page_template( [$myvar]  ) ) {
...
}
}
```

Comment: try reading up on [scope](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) :)

Comment: @peter possibly yes, however still getting the error

Comment: Look for the 'Extending the scope of variables into anonymous functions' part in the linked answer. So it should be like this: `function se_remove_styles() use($myVar) {` `if ( is_page_template( $myvar ) ) {`

Comment: @Beep because $myVar is not in function scope.. hence the link/dupe

Comment: @treyBake im with you, thought it may be something like it needs to be within the function, so how to set it as a global var so that I can use in multiple functions

Comment: I updated my comment here with the specific part

Comment: Inside the function, just add `global $myvar;` as the first line.

Comment: ^^although that works, using globals is hardly ever the answer. Creating a class with a __construct method to set vars is a much better practice.

Comment: I see, perfect thanks guys, been working with JS so long now basic PHP knowledge is gone. I know it was a stupid question thanks for the help in getting this working